# Populate UITableview data instantly on UITextField value change

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS.

I want to achieve functionality similar to google places autocomplete in Facebook. Where on every key press, appropriate data gets populated instantly. I have written a function where data gets populated as per the value in my UITextField. But it happens once the user clicks on “Return” key. (As i have called this function on “textFieldDidEndEditing” delegate method). So, I need help to know where (which delegate method) to call my function to populate the appropriate UITableView data instantly according to text change in my UITextField.

```
- (void)MyFunctionToGetData
{
    MyJSONURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.myurl.com?input=%@",txtMyText.text];
    dispatch_async(GDQueue, ^{Mydata = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: MyJSONURL]];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject: Mydata waitUntilDone:YES]; });
}

- (void)MyFunctionTofetchedData:(NSMutableData *)responseData
{
NSError* error;    
MyArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: Mydata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
[tblMyTable reloadData];
}

//TableView delegate methods start
-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [MyArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];   
 if (cell==nil)
{    
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSString * strDataText = [[MyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@“myKey"];           cell.textLabel.text = strDataText;   
return cell;

  }

  // I am calling my function here. By doing this i can get results once i edit the text and then click “Return” key. Whereas i want the different result on each key press action on that textfield.

  - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

  {
   [self MyFunctionToGetData];


  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, this way, you should use the following TextField delegate method:

```
textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
return YES;
```

}, this method is called everytime when a keyboard button is pressed. hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and in the method

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
NSLog( @"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);
}
```

you can see the current text in the textfield. Everytime the user types a new char, and you populate your tableView

Comment: Please find the sample code added here. This is the way I am doing. Thanks!

Comment: what submitRequest method is doing?

Comment: Sorry it should be "MyFunctionToGetData" instead of "submitRequest"

Comment: your method should be myFunctionToGetDataContainingString: (NSString *)string; 
an based on that string you will get only the data wich starts with that string, so you could populate the tableView with the data you want